# I have ubuntu and win 10 in dual boot it shows GNU grub2 error

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have i7 7th gen with nvidia GTX 1050 with 8GB ram, 128 GB ssd and 1TB hdd.
I had just win 10 installed on my **SSD** then i installed ubuntu 18.04 lts alongside windows without swap on my **HDD**. I couldnt shutdown or reboot my ubuntu so I formatted ubuntu partiton from win10 disc manager then when i rebooted it showed *GNU GRUB2 error.* 
I can boot into windows so I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 on the same drive as of ubuntu 18.04 (this time with swap partition). But I dont think that worked and i see the same grub2 error screen again. I can give windows boot manager upper priority and boot into win. But **how can i fix my grub or completely remove it from my system?**

Comment: If you have UEFI, you just need to use UEFI boot manager (menu), Same f10 or f12 you used to boot flash drive. And then boot Windows entry. But to remove grub entries & ubuntu folder see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi You probably needed 18.04, but perhaps boot parameter(s) depending on your system to have Ubuntu work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something similar, and I just wanted to get back to Windows only. You need to fix the boot record of your disk - something like https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/repair-mbr-windows-10.html or https://www.pcworld.com/article/3113585/windows/how-to-repair-windows-master-boot-record-and-fix-your-bricked-pc.html

What I ended up doing was:

1. Use ubuntu live usb stick to erase the ubuntu partitions and resize
   the windows partition to use the new free space - I used gparted for this.
2. Create a windows 10 installation usb stick and repair the boot record.

I strongly recommend having a second system available to create usb sticks and google stuff.

Comment: My win10 is running fine. I just have problem with that grub2 and I want to use linux.